# form submission status success/fail

Tags: c#, javascript, forms, rest, post

I have a very simple form like so...

```
<form id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/api/test/Post" method="post">
    <input name="file2" type="file" />
    <input type="text" name="text1" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="click click" />
</form>
```

This in turns call a RESTful service which looks like....

```
public void Post()
    {
        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        string value1 = httpRequest .Form["text1"];
        //do stuff with the form data submitted

        var files = new List<string>();

        foreach(string file in httpRequest .Files)
        {
            var postfeild = httpRequest .Files[file];
            //do stuff
        }          
    }
```

When the submit button is pressed on the form, the page refreshes. I would like to tell the user if their form has been submitted successfully, if there was an error, or redirect them to another page.

Is this possible to achieve at all? I thought about making an ajax call and just sending over stringified data, however, having files complicates things.

Is there anything I can do through C# or JavaScript to achieve the desired result?

Comment: just send a viewbag property with after post. and show/hide your success div based on that value.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to POST via AJAX and respond with a JSON object that contains status/message.  However if you want to keep it classic then you'd have to inject some javascript that will run upon load.

As for using javascript with web forms:  (it's been a while since I've used it..)

pcode at best:

```
<% if ( someVariable == true ){  Response.Write("alert('successful update of blah');"); } %>
```

Comment: I would have loved to use AJAX but it becomes problematic with the files. The HTML5 file api is sadly nonexistent in IE8 :( But could you elaborate a little bit? What will I be checking with the javascript on the form load?

Answer (score 0):

You can add some sort of alert after the page reloads due to a form submission. You just need to set some sort of flag before you submit the form and set it back after the message is displayed. It will need to be a server side flag, a JS variable will be erased.

You could also switch to AJAX with jQuery and you can submit a form without refreshing the page.

Comment: I would. But jQuery AJAX does not support files. That is I cannot send files to the server through an AJAX call.